# Merging nested lists based on the first element of a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a large list of lists that contains some data.

```
[['', 'A', 'B'],['C', '', 'D'],['E', 'F', ''],['', 'H', 'I'],['J', 'K', ''],['L', 'M', 'N']]
```

The data represented in those lists are connected. When the first element of a nested list is `''`, I know for certainty that every list after that, should be apart of the list that began with an element of `''`. Every list that is, until the next list that has a first element of `''`. Then the cycle repeats. Any of the lists can contain `''` at any element. It is only when the first element is `''` that the cycle repeats.

I'm hoping to find a quick way of creating a new list of lists from the above list of lists that produces the expected outcome below.

```
[['', 'A', 'B', 'C', '', 'D', 'E', 'F', ''],['', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', '', 'L', 'M', 'N']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
a = [['', 'A', 'B'],['C', '', 'D'],['E', 'F', ''],['', 'H', 'I'],['J', 'K', ''],['L', 'M', 'N']]

final = []

for i in a:
    if i[0] == "":
        final.append([])    
    final[-1].extend(i) 

print(final)
```

**Output**

```
[['', 'A', 'B', 'C', '', 'D', 'E', 'F', ''], ['', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', '', 'L', 'M', 'N']]
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one answer:

```
lst = [['', 'A', 'B'],['C', '', 'D'],['E', 'F', ''],['', 'H', 'I'],['J', 'K', ''],['L', 'M', 'N']]
result = []
temp = []
for l in lst:
    if len(l[0]) == 0 and len(temp) == 0:
        temp.extend(l)
    elif len(temp) != 0:
        temp.extend(l)
        if len(l[-1]) == 0:
            result.append(temp)
            temp = []
result
```

Output:

```
[['', 'A', 'B', 'C', '', 'D', 'E', 'F', ''], ['', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', '']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
data=[['', 'A', 'B'],['C', '', 'D'],['E', 'F', ''],['', 'H', 'I'],['J', 'K', ''],['L', 'M', 'N']]

new_list = []
for l in data:
    if l and l[0]=='':
        new_list.append([])
        new_list[-1].extend(l)
    else:
        new_list[-1].extend(l)
print(new_list)
```

An empty list is appended to the list to be output (in this case `new_list`) whenever a sublist with first element `''` is found in `data`.

New elements are added to the last sublist in the current value of `new_list`.

Output is:

```
[['', 'A', 'B', 'C', '', 'D', 'E', 'F', ''], ['', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', '', 'L', 'M', 'N']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in two stages, first find the indices of the ones that start with `''`, then iterate over those indices and create the sub-list:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

lst = [['', 'A', 'B'], ['C', '', 'D'], ['E', 'F', ''], ['', 'H', 'I'], ['J', 'K', ''], ['L', 'M', 'N']]

# find the indices
starts = [i for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e[0] == '']

# iterate over the indices in pairs (current, next)
result = [list(chain.from_iterable(lst[start:end])) for start, end in zip_longest(starts, starts[1:], fillvalue=len(lst))]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['', 'A', 'B', 'C', '', 'D', 'E', 'F', ''], ['', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', '', 'L', 'M', 'N']]
```